# Federated authentication user is getting logged in as interface user not as normal virtual user

Tags: sitecore-client, federated-authentication

This is my config file for the federated authentication.

```
<configuration
xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
<sitecore>
<settings>
  <!-- Third party app and secret id -->
  <setting name="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Facebook.AppId" value="*" />
  <setting name="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Facebook.AppSecret" value="*" />

  <setting name="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Google.ClientId" value="*" />
  <setting name="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Google.ClientSecret" value="*" />

  <!-- Setting to enable the federation authentication -->
  <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled">
    <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
  </setting>
</settings>

<!-- Sitecore services registration required for the federated authentication -->
<services>
  <!--<configurator type="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Areas.Main.Infrastructure.Configurator.ServicesConfigurator, MRDNA.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true"/>-->
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
</services>

<pipelines>
  <owin.identityProviders>
    <!-- Processors for coniguring providers. Each provider must have its own processor-->
    <processor type="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Areas.Main.Infrastructure.Pipelines.IdentityProviders.Facebook, MRDNA.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true" />
    <processor type="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Areas.Main.Infrastructure.Pipelines.IdentityProviders.Google, MRDNA.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true" />
  </owin.identityProviders>
  <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    <processor type="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Areas.Main.Infrastructure.Pipelines.SignedIn.TrackSignedIn, MRDNA.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true" />
  </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
</pipelines>


<federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">

  <!-- List of identity providers -->
  <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
    <!-- Facebook provider -->
    <identityProvider id="Facebook" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <param desc="name">Facebook</param>
      <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
      <caption>Facebook</caption>
      <domain>extranet</domain>
      <triggerExternalSignOut>false</triggerExternalSignOut>
      <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation" />
    </identityProvider>

    <!-- Google provider -->
    <identityProvider id="Google" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <param desc="name">Google</param>
      <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
      <caption>Google</caption>
      <domain>extranet</domain>
      <triggerExternalSignOut>false</triggerExternalSignOut>
      <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation" />
    </identityProvider>
  </identityProviders>

  <!--Provider mappings to sites-->
  <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
    <mapEntry name="provider entry" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>main</site>
      </sites>

      <!-- Registered identity providers for above providers -->
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Facebook']" />
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Google']" />
      </identityProviders>
      <!--<externalUserBuilder type="MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Areas.Main.Infrastructure.Builder.CustomProviderUserBuilder, MRDNA.Feature.Accounts" resolve="true">
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>-->
      <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <IsPersistentUser>false</IsPersistentUser>
      </externalUserBuilder>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>

  <!--List of all shared transformations-->
  <sharedTransformations/>

  <!--Property mappings initializer-->
  <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">

    <!--List of property mappings
            Note that all mappings from the list will be applied to each providers-->
    <maps hint="list">
      <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <source name="email" />
          <target name="Email" />
        </data>
      </map>
      <map name="full_name" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <source name="full_name" />
          <target name="FullName" />
        </data>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </propertyInitializer>
</federatedAuthentication>


</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is my custom provider for google

```
public class Google : IdentityProvidersProcessor
{
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Google"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="federatedAuthenticationConfiguration"></param>
    /// <param name="cookieManager"></param>
    /// <param name="settings"></param>
    public Google(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
                    ICookieManager cookieManager,
                    BaseSettings settings)
                    : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Class Variables

    protected override string IdentityProviderName => "Google";

    #endregion

    protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
        var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();

        var options = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            Caption = identityProvider.Caption,
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            ClientId = Settings.GetSetting("MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Google.ClientId"),
            ClientSecret = Settings.GetSetting("MRDNA.Feature.Accounts.Google.ClientSecret"),
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
                    AddClaim(context, "full_name", "name");
                    AddClaim(context, "email", "email");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            },
            Scope =
            {
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
            }
        };
        GoogleAuthenticationExtensions.UseGoogleAuthentication(args.App, options);
    }

    #region Subroutines

    private void AddClaim(GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext context, string claimName, string propertyName)
    {
        var value = context.User[propertyName]?.ToString();
        if (propertyName == "picture")
        {
            value = context.User["picture"]?["data"]?["url"]?.ToString();
            if (value == null)
                return;
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture_url", value));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture_mime", "image/jpg"));
            return;
        }

        if (value == null)
            return;
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimName, value));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is my trackSigenIn pipeline processor

```
public class TrackSignedIn : SignedInProcessor
{
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TrackSignedIn"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accountService">The account service</param>
    /// <param name="federatedAuthenticationConfiguration">The federated authentication configuration</param>
    public TrackSignedIn(IAccountService accountService, FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration)
    {
        this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration = federatedAuthenticationConfiguration;
        this.AccountService = accountService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the federated authentication configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The federated authentication configuration.
    /// </value>
    private FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the account service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The account service.
    /// </value>
    private IAccountService AccountService { get; }

    #endregion

    public override void Process(SignedInArgs args)
    {
        //Do not track the user signin if this is a response to a membership provider login
        var claimIdentity = args.Context.Identity;
        var provider = this.GetProvider(claimIdentity);
        if (provider.Name == Constants.LocalIdentityProvider || provider.Name == "SitecoreIdentityServer")
        {
            return;
        }
        var name = claimIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type.Equals("full_name")).Value;
        var email = claimIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type.Equals("email")).Value;
        var idp = claimIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type.Equals("idp")).Value;
        var innerUser = args.User.InnerUser;
        var userName = $"{innerUser.Domain.Name}\\{innerUser.Profile.Email}-{DateTime.Now.Ticks}";
        this.AccountService.LoginBySocialConnector(email, name, idp, args.User.InnerUser);
    }

    private IdentityProvider GetProvider(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        return this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration.GetIdentityProvider(identity);
    }
}
```

But when i am login more than two time using google or facebook i am getting issue **The maximum number of simultaneously active (logged-in) editors exceeded. The User google\ci2ZOx1G7L cannot be logged in to the system. The maximum of editors allowed by license is 2.** So why it is getting logged in as interface user not as normal virtual user? Any clue

Comment: try creating a new domain and map in config file instead of extranet. your license restricts only 2 sitecore users

Comment: I tried with facebook and gmail domain but still getting the same issue.

Comment: I had implemented fed auth for Azure ADb2C similar way - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/how-to-get-sitecore-context-user-after-redirect-from-azure-adb2c-login  has the code base and config files. Probably might help you

Comment: Any luck finding the fix? We have the same issue on Sitecore 9.3 while logging external users with AD B2C :( [Please treat it as a comment as i don't have enough reputation to add one]