# How to modify CookieAuthentication options in Sitecore 9?

Tags: federated-authentication, owin, azure-b2c

In Sitecore 9.2, we would like to change some of the CookieAuthenticationOptions, that are used for Authentication.

This is the code we would use:

```
args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        CookiePath = "/",
#if !DEBUG
        CookieDomain = ".customdomain.com",
#endif
        TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector()),
        LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/auth/sso/login"),
        LogoutPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/auth/sso/logout"),
    },

    // It seems there are issues with the ordering of Forms Authentication (Sitecore) and this OWIN middleware. Therefore we run this middleware 
    // at the IIS pipeline stage right after Forms Authentication (Authenticate stage) to ensure the order is deterministic.
    PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);
```

How and where would I hook into the Owin pipeline in Sitecore 9.2 to achieve this?

Comment: which middleware do you need this for Azure ADb2C ?

Comment: Yes, we need it for Azure Ad b2c

Comment: Ok , once you plugged in your middleware , does the above code not work ?

Comment: Where do I plug it in? The Sitecore Owin .dll's already add CookieAuthentication, so I would guess I have to overwrite that somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly , but every middlewware can inject or implement its own cookieauthentication options. see below code and this questions - [How to get Sitecore.Context.User after redirect from Azure ADb2c login?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/how-to-get-sitecore-context-user-after-redirect-from-azure-adb2c-login)

```
protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();

            args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(EditProfilePolicyId));
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ResetPasswordPolicyId));
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - that is exactly what I want to do. When I try the above code, I get the dreaded "Error: Unsuccessful login with external provider" when trying to login to Sitecore or when browsing the enduser website.Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: ok , maybe you could put a debug breakpoint to check where the error occurs in the file. Pl edit the question and add the complete code.cs file for better understanding. Also , while testing test the login in multiple browsers/incognito mode , it could be due to stored cookies as well

Comment: For some reason, the original code I posted worked all of a sudden. Maybe it was due to old cookies or similar as you suggested.
I can accept your answer as the solution even though it was the code I originally posted, that ended up workin for me.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: glad , it worked out for ya.